# Imagem de alguns itens não é atualizada ao modificar a ordem da lista

Tags: javascript, react

Estou com problemas em manter as imagens na posição correta. Tenho uma lista de imagens, mas quando eu clico no filtro para inverter a ordem, algumas imagens mantém a sua posição.

Para melhor entendimento eu fiz um exemplo bem limpo e fácil de compreender que simula um problema parecido:

```js
const api = [
  {
    name: "Elephant",
    url:
      "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1e/06/e1/1e06e107f0ca520aed316957b685ef5c.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Wallpaper Windoes",
    url: "https://img.ibxk.com.br/2015/07/23/23170425700729.jpg?w=328"
  },
  { name: "No image", url: "" },
  { name: "Tiger", url: "https://www.htmlecsspro.com/exemple/img/imagem.jpg" },
  {
    name: "Lion",
    url:
      "https://blogmedia.evbstatic.com/wp-content/uploads/wpmulti/sites/18/2014/07/24025147/6BaVde_t20_VKbpQ7-e1527130375674.jpg"
  },
  { name: "No image 2", url: "" },
  {
    name: "Google",
    url:
      "https://tecnoblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/google-imagens-700x394.jpg"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [itemsList, setItemsList] = React.useState([]);
  const [isInverted, setIsInverted] = React.useState(false);

  function reverseAction() {
    setIsInverted(isInverted ? false : true);
    setItemsList(api.reverse());
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setItemsList(api);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={reverseAction}>Reverse</button>
      <p>{isInverted ? "true" : "false"}</p>
      {itemsList.map((item, index) => (
        <Cards key={index} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const IMG_DEFAULT = 'https://www.luzeoliveira.com.br/index/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/default.png';

function Cards({ item }) {
  const [img, setImg] = React.useState(IMG_DEFAULT);

  //Os itens tem uma imagem padrão, mas a imagem é alterada se o item tiver sua propria imagem
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (item.url.length > 1) {
      setImg(item.url);
    }
  }, []);

  //se ocorrer erro ao carregar a imagem do item, então volta para a imagem padrão
  function onErrorImg() {
    setImg(IMG_DEFAULT);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{item.name}</p>
      <img style={{height: 200 }} src={img} alt="img" onError={onErrorImg} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu vejo dois problemas no exemplo que você criou:

- O `useEffect` no `<Card>` possui um array de dependências errado.

Antes da edição na pergunta, não possuia um array de dependências, então, o `useEffect` era executado em todo render. Depois da edição, você colocou `[]`, o que faz com que ele seja executado apenas na primeira vez, por isso as imagens não trocam mais.

O correto seria `[item.url]`, pois você quer atualizar a imagem sempre que ela mudar:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //...
}, [item.url]);
```

- Seu `if`, no `useEffect` do `<Card>`, não atualiza a imagem quando o item não tem uma URL (`''`).

Você deveria colocar a URL padrão, nesse caso. Por isso, antes da sua edição na pergunta, todas imagens trocavam de lugar corretamente, com exceção das sem imagem.

Para corrigir isso, basta adicionar a imagem padrão se não possuir URL:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const url = item.url === '' ? IMG_DEFAULT : item.url;
    setImg(url);
}, [item.url]);
```

O exemplo corrigido fica assim:

```js
const api = [
  {
    name: "Elephant",
    url:
      "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1e/06/e1/1e06e107f0ca520aed316957b685ef5c.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Wallpaper Windoes",
    url: "https://img.ibxk.com.br/2015/07/23/23170425700729.jpg?w=328"
  },
  { name: "No image", url: "" },
  { name: "Tiger", url: "https://www.htmlecsspro.com/exemple/img/imagem.jpg" },
  {
    name: "Lion",
    url:
      "https://blogmedia.evbstatic.com/wp-content/uploads/wpmulti/sites/18/2014/07/24025147/6BaVde_t20_VKbpQ7-e1527130375674.jpg"
  },
  { name: "No image 2", url: "" },
  {
    name: "Google",
    url:
      "https://tecnoblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/google-imagens-700x394.jpg"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [itemsList, setItemsList] = React.useState([]);
  const [isInverted, setIsInverted] = React.useState(false);

  function reverseAction() {
    setIsInverted(isInverted ? false : true);
    setItemsList(api.reverse());
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setItemsList(api);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={reverseAction}>Reverse</button>
      <p>{isInverted ? "true" : "false"}</p>
      {itemsList.map((item, index) => (
        <Cards key={index} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const IMG_DEFAULT = 'https://www.luzeoliveira.com.br/index/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/default.png';

function Cards({ item }) {
  const [img, setImg] = React.useState(IMG_DEFAULT);

  //Os itens tem uma imagem padrão, mas a imagem é alterada se o item tiver sua propria imagem
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const url = item.url === '' ? IMG_DEFAULT : item.url;
    setImg(url);
  }, [item.url]);

  //se ocorrer erro ao carregar a imagem do item, então volta para a imagem padrão
  function onErrorImg() {
    setImg(IMG_DEFAULT);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{item.name}</p>
      <img style={{height: 200 }} src={img} alt="img" onError={onErrorImg} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```